# mySQL delete w/ join or subquery

Tags: mysql

I have a select query which works:

```
SELECT    actions.id
FROM      actions
LEFT JOIN users
ON        users.id = actions.user_id
WHERE     users.id is null;
```

And I wanted to delete these records. I tried changing the select line to "DELETE" which produced an error. I also tried a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM actions WHERE id IN (
    SELECT    actions.id
    FROM      actions
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON        users.id = actions.user_id
    WHERE     users.id is null
);
```

Both attempts cause errors. While I've already solved the problem via PHP, it seems like this ought to be something the database can do with a single command. Is there a way?

The query is basically selecting all the rows in `actions` that do not have a corresponding entry in `users` ( the tables in question are now using foreign keys so this issue won't happen again ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE    actions
FROM     actions
LEFT JOIN users
ON        users.id = actions.user_id
WHERE     users.id is null;
```

More info at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't like it if you try to DELETE/UPDATE rows and SELECT them in the same query.  To solve this, they support a multi-table DELETE syntax.

```
DELETE a FROM actions a
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.id = a.user_id
WHERE u.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way - recently bought your book. Good stuff.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm glad that you enjoyed my book, [SQL Antipatterns: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming.](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns)  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE actions  
    FROM actions LEFT JOIN
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON        users.id = actions.user_id
    WHERE     users.id is null
```